# Proof that divergence of stress-energy tensor is zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Because of conservations laws, $$T^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=0$$ where ${}_{,\nu}$ is the covariant derivative. If $$T^{\mu\nu}=\rho u^\mu u^\nu$$ where $u=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ and $\tau$ is proper time, can we reach that conclusion just by deriving?

My attempt:

$$T^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=[\rho u^\mu u^\nu]_{,\nu}=\rho u^\mu_{,\nu} u^\nu+\rho u^\mu u^\nu_{,\nu}=\rho a^\mu+\rho u^\mu u^\nu_{,\nu}$$

(as $a^\mu=\frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}=\frac{du^\mu}{dx^\nu}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=u^\mu_{,\nu} u^\nu$) but I don't see how this is zero in all frames of reference.

Comment: You need the corresponding equation of motion. This is similar to asking "if $E = mv^2/2$, how do I show that $dE/dt = 0$?"

Comment: @Aaron It's a pressureless fluid (dust), so maybe no interactions means $a^\mu=0$. What about the other term?

Comment: @Aaron the question is implicitly assuming that motion is along geodesics, which gives the equations of motion.

Comment: The second term vanishing is just a statement of momentum conservation (in an incompressible fluid).